# How can I extend a class in Node JS by my custom constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, model, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I have the following in a `Node Js` model. This file exists in another project that cannot be changed but is locally available to the other projects.

```
module.exports = {
    base: require('*/cartridge/models/product/decorators/base'),
    availability: require('*/cartridge/models/product/decorators/availability')
};
```

All the methods here act like `constructors` of the `class Product`. Now I want to add another attribute that should be available when I try to access `Product.badge`. For this, I have tried to extend the above model in the following way:

```
var indexBase = require('*/cartridge/models/product/decorators/index');

indexBase.badge = require('*/cartridge/models/product/decorators/badge');

module.exports = indexBase;
```

But it seems throw an error, I have tried to log the `Badge Type`, but I still cannot access the badge type here.

I am calling the above object as the following:

```
var decorators = require('*/cartridge/models/product/decorators/index');
decorators.badge(product, variantProduct);
```

I want to know how can I extend an existing class as I want to add a custom `constructor`?

*Here only the syntax is based on `Node Js` but this code is written for SFRA in Salesforce B2C Commerce.*

Comment: If you want to extend a class just make a class and use the extend syntax for ES6. Or you can use the prototypal inheritance for ES5 https://medium.com/ecmascript-2015/es6-classes-and-inheritance-607804080906

Comment: @AritraChakraborty, thanks, I will try that, this might be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is in the `index.js` file:

```
var indexBase = module.superModule;
```

instead of:

```
var indexBase = require('*/cartridge/models/product/decorators/index');
```

and it will work perfectly fine.